# django ImageField not saving files in proper directory via django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When post request is sent the images is saved in **media/user_None/pic/1602746423.311224_profile.png** instead of **media/user_{id}/pic/1602746423.311224_profile.png**

**Teacher Model**

```
class Teacher(AbstractUser):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Profile Picture",blank=True,null=True,upload_to=file_pic,default='default.png')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date Of Birth', null=True)
    doj = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date Of Join', null=True)
    mobile_num = models.CharField(verbose_name='Mobile Number',max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)

    SEX_CHOICE = (
        ('m','Male'),
        ('f','Female'),
        ('t','Transgender'),
        ('o','Others')
    )
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=SEX_CHOICE,default='m')
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

**file_pic function for ImageField, to save photos in users folder based on its id**

```
def file_pic(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/pic/{2}_{1}'.format(instance.id, filename, time.time())
```

**Serializer for teacher creation**

```
class TeacherCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password2 = CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type':'password'})
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'mobile_num',
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'last_name',
            'dob',
            'doj',
            'sex',
            'department',
            'profile_pic',
            'password',
            'password2'
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {'write_only':True, 'style':{'input_type':'password'}}
        }

    def create(self,validated_data):
        vd_cpy = validated_data
        password1 = vd_cpy['password']
        password2 = vd_cpy['password2']
        vd_cpy.pop('password2')
        vd_cpy.pop('password')
        teacher = Teacher(**vd_cpy)

        if(password1!=password2):
            raise ValidationError('password doesn\'t match')
        teacher.set_password(password1)
        teacher.save()
        return validated_data
    
    def validate_mobile_num(self,value):
        value = self.initial_data.get('mobile_num',None)
        if value is None or len(value) == 0:
            return None
        if(re.search(r'^((\+?91|0)?){1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$',value) is None):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid Mobile Number')
        return value
    
    def validate_email(self,value):
        if(Teacher.objects.filter(email=value).exists()):
            raise ValidationError('email already registered')
        return value
```

**APIView for teacher creation**

```
class TeacherCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Teacher.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeacherCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,FormParser,MultiPartParser)
```

**What DRF API explorer shows just after registering**

```
HTTP 201 Created
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "username": "ramverma",
    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
    "mobile_num": null,
    "first_name": "Ram",
    "middle_name": "",
    "last_name": "Verma",
    "dob": null,
    "doj": null,
    "sex": "m",
    "department": 6,
    "profile_pic": http://localhost:8000/media/user_None/pic/1602764174.8516657_ProfiePic.png
}

**1st Issue**
```

**profile_pic is saved in folder **user_none** but instead it should be save in **user_{user.id}** as written in file_pic function. Idea is to save everything related to user in one folder.

```
 {
        "profile_pic": "http://localhost:8000/media/user_None/pic/1602764174.8516657_ProfiePic.png",
        "first_name": "Ram",
        "last_name": "Verma",
        "username": "ramverma",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/teacher/23"
    }
```

**2nd Issue**
If no profile pic is given in POST request, then profile_pic value is set to null, instead of default that is provided in ImageFiled in model

both issues occur when API interaction is done, in web interaction problem doesn't persist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access object id you have to save() it first since [the value is calculated by the database and not by django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys) and there is no way to know it before. You can then update the ImageField by calling the [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-save).

I am not sure about the default image problem.